# Using an Asterisks in a Comment

Tags: support

I had a comment on one of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28299761/2642059) which asked me to add a "*" to my output. (The comment is now deleted.)

I tried to respond in a comment, but I couldn't output a single asterisk in a comment containing two asterisks. How do I do that without being able to put the single asterisks in separate paragraphs?

Comment: You mean that the 2 separate asterisks were formatting the text between them in italics?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes like this: asterisk here: "*" another asterisk: "*" They seem to be fine in open space, but not when surrounded by quotation marks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escape the asterisk with a backslash to have it rendered as a `*` instead of making the text *italic*:

```
\*I am text*
```

will render as:

*I am text*

[This section of the markdown spec](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash) covers this behavior and includes a list of escapable characters.

Comment: HAHA! "\*" This works! "\*"

Comment: I know this is off-topic but don't you love how the spec is in such a blog-styled page? It's like some guy decided to randomly post this idea for a markup language and people began using it for themselves over the years. So unconventional.

Comment: Needing *just* the right word to end a comment on another page (about how I spend too long looking for solutions to the "littlest coding issues"), I ended up here...  just so I could figure out how to type `*\*sigh**` ... *\*sigh**

Comment: ...but now, what if I wanted to keep the word italic like that, but make the asterisks bold??                         **ಠ⌣ಠ**

Comment: @ashleedawg Just use HTML at that point; it'll make your life much easier.

Comment: @Servy -- HTML in Stack Overflow comments?  ...like <b>this</b> or <strong>this</strong>?!   ;-)